# Numpy modify 2D Array inplace

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have this 2D array.

```
[(476301.98163511883, 6176897.129456658)
 (476723.365551495, 6176895.078376785)
 (477124.59457628336, 6176893.28525448)
 (477525.82249430567, 6176891.306532074)
 (477927.0510582989, 6176889.4760845825)
 (477925.0121537624, 6176487.379134962)
 (477922.97333802003, 6176085.2824224755)
 (477920.93404681794, 6175683.074655607)
 (477918.79328165855, 6175260.834659822)]
```

I'm trying to add 10 to "X" the first column and 20 to the "Y" column. I can't figure out how to access each column while keeping the array structure as is.

I can do something like this

```
x = array['X'] + 10
y = array['Y'] + 20
```

However now the array is split and a need the x, y pair together like in the original array. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your columns are named 'X' and 'Y', and that array is a `numpy.array`?
In that case you can edit inplace by using the `+=` operator:

```
array['X'] += 10
array['Y'] += 20
```

or, if they are not named

```
array[:, 0] += 10
array[:, 1] += 20
```

This is the same as

```
array['X'] = array['X'] + 10
```